# Python: Bloomberg API is not authorized

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I am trying to pull data from Bloomberg using Python API. API package comes with example codes and the programs that only requires local host work perfectly. However, the programs that uses other authorization ways are always stuck with the error:

```
Connecting to port 8194 on localhost
TokenGenerationFailure = {
    reason = {
        source = "apitkns (apiauth) on ebbdbp-ob-053"
        category = "NO_AUTH"
        errorCode = 12
        description = "User not in emrs userid=NA\mds firm=22691"
        subcategory = "INVALID_USER"
    }
}

Failed to get token
No authorization
```

I saw one more person having similar problem but instead of solving it he chose to just use local host. I can't always use localhost because I will have to assist and troubleshoot for other users. So I need a hint how to overcome this error.

My question is how can I set the userid anything other than `OS_LOGON` which automatically uses the login credentials of my account so that I can use other users' name when needed? I tried to change `OS_LOGON` with the user name but it didn't work.

The full program I am trying to run is:

```
"""SnapshotRequestTemplateExample.py"""
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import datetime
from optparse import OptionParser, OptionValueError

import blpapi

TOKEN_SUCCESS = blpapi.Name("TokenGenerationSuccess")
TOKEN_FAILURE = blpapi.Name("TokenGenerationFailure")
AUTHORIZATION_SUCCESS = blpapi.Name("AuthorizationSuccess")
TOKEN = blpapi.Name("token")


def authOptionCallback(_option, _opt, value, parser):
    vals = value.split('=', 1)

    if value == "user":
        parser.values.auth = "AuthenticationType=OS_LOGON"
    elif value == "none":
        parser.values.auth = None
    elif vals[0] == "app" and len(vals) == 2:
        parser.values.auth = "AuthenticationMode=APPLICATION_ONLY;"\
            "ApplicationAuthenticationType=APPNAME_AND_KEY;"\
            "ApplicationName=" + vals[1]
    elif vals[0] == "userapp" and len(vals) == 2:
        parser.values.auth = "AuthenticationMode=USER_AND_APPLICATION;"\
            "AuthenticationType=OS_LOGON;"\
            "ApplicationAuthenticationType=APPNAME_AND_KEY;"\
            "ApplicationName=" + vals[1]
    elif vals[0] == "dir" and len(vals) == 2:
        parser.values.auth = "AuthenticationType=DIRECTORY_SERVICE;"\
            "DirSvcPropertyName=" + vals[1]
    else:
        raise OptionValueError("Invalid auth option '%s'" % value)


def parseCmdLine():
    """parse cli arguments"""
    parser = OptionParser(description="Retrieve realtime data.")
    parser.add_option("-a",
                      "--ip",
                      dest="hosts",
                      help="server name or IP (default: localhost)",
                      metavar="ipAddress",
                      action="append",
                      default=[])
    parser.add_option("-p",
                      dest="port",
                      type="int",
                      help="server port (default: %default)",
                      metavar="tcpPort",
                      default=8194)
    parser.add_option("--auth",
                      dest="auth",
                      help="authentication option: "
                      "user|none|app=<app>|userapp=<app>|dir=<property>"
                      " (default: %default)",
                      metavar="option",
                      action="callback",
                      callback=authOptionCallback,
                      type="string",
                      default="user")

    (opts, _) = parser.parse_args()

    if not opts.hosts:
        opts.hosts = ["localhost"]

    if not opts.topics:
        opts.topics = ["/ticker/IBM US Equity"]

    return opts


def authorize(authService, identity, session, cid):
    """authorize the session for identity via authService"""
    tokenEventQueue = blpapi.EventQueue()
    session.generateToken(eventQueue=tokenEventQueue)

    # Process related response
    ev = tokenEventQueue.nextEvent()
    token = None
    if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.TOKEN_STATUS or \
            ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.REQUEST_STATUS:
        for msg in ev:
            print(msg)
            if msg.messageType() == TOKEN_SUCCESS:
                token = msg.getElementAsString(TOKEN)
            elif msg.messageType() == TOKEN_FAILURE:
                break

    if not token:
        print("Failed to get token")
        return False

    # Create and fill the authorization request
    authRequest = authService.createAuthorizationRequest()
    authRequest.set(TOKEN, token)

    # Send authorization request to "fill" the Identity
    session.sendAuthorizationRequest(authRequest, identity, cid)

    # Process related responses
    startTime = datetime.datetime.today()
    WAIT_TIME_SECONDS = 10
    while True:
        event = session.nextEvent(WAIT_TIME_SECONDS * 1000)
        if event.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE or \
                event.eventType() == blpapi.Event.REQUEST_STATUS or \
                event.eventType() == blpapi.Event.PARTIAL_RESPONSE:
            for msg in event:
                print(msg)
                if msg.messageType() == AUTHORIZATION_SUCCESS:
                    return True
                print("Authorization failed")
                return False

        endTime = datetime.datetime.today()
        if endTime - startTime > datetime.timedelta(seconds=WAIT_TIME_SECONDS):
            return False


def main():
    """main entry point"""
    global options
    options = parseCmdLine()

    # Fill SessionOptions
    sessionOptions = blpapi.SessionOptions()
    for idx, host in enumerate(options.hosts):
        sessionOptions.setServerAddress(host, options.port, idx)
    sessionOptions.setAuthenticationOptions(options.auth)
    sessionOptions.setAutoRestartOnDisconnection(True)

    print("Connecting to port %d on %s" % (
        options.port, ", ".join(options.hosts)))

    session = blpapi.Session(sessionOptions)

    if not session.start():
        print("Failed to start session.")
        return

    subscriptionIdentity = None
    if options.auth:
        subscriptionIdentity = session.createIdentity()
        isAuthorized = False
        authServiceName = "//blp/apiauth"
        if session.openService(authServiceName):
            authService = session.getService(authServiceName)
            isAuthorized = authorize(authService, subscriptionIdentity,
                                     session, blpapi.CorrelationId("auth"))
        if not isAuthorized:
            print("No authorization")
            return
    else:
        print("Not using authorization")
.
.
.
.
.
    finally:
        session.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("SnapshotRequestTemplateExample")
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Ctrl+C pressed. Stopping...")
```

Comment: Whoa, this is way too much code to troubleshoot. Trim it down to an MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: In my experience when using the Bloomi API, I don't supply any login credentials to the Session object. The API talks to the bbcomm process which is already running on the client PC. The bbcomm process is started when you log into a Bloomi terminal (and supply username, pwd and bio-metric id).  I don't see how you can impersonate the login credentials of a different user. NB. Even if you succeeded, you would log that user out of Bloomberg wherever they were using it, as Bloomberg only allows one session per user.

Comment: Although I am connecting to the localhost as you can see in the first line of the error message, the example program Bloomberg provided with Python API has a long code and functions that requires authorization step. I am trying to connect without any authorization request or option including "none".

For now I am not worried about other users too much because I am still trying to analyze and understand how can I use the API most efficiently. I mentioned them because if I can find a solution without OS_LOGON, I can use it on mine, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example is intended for Bloomberg's BPIPE product and as such includes the necessary authorization code.  For this example, if you're connecting to the Desktop API (typically localhost:8194) you would want to pass an auth parameter of "none".  Note that this example is for the mktdata snapshot functionality which isn't supported by Desktop API.

You state you're trying to troubleshoot on behalf of other users, presumably traders using BPIPE under their credentials.  In this case you would need to create an Identity object to represent that user.

This would be done thusly:

```
# Create and fill the authorization request
authRequest = authService.createAuthorizationRequest()
authRequest.set("authId", STRING_CONTAINING_USERS_EMRS_LOGON)
authRequest.set("ipAddress", STRING_OF_IP_ADDRESS_WHERE_USER_IS_LOGGED_INTO_TERMINAL)

# Send authorization request to "fill" the Identity
session.sendAuthorizationRequest(authRequest, identity, cid)
```

Please be aware of potential licensing compliance issues when using this approach as this can have serious consequences.  If in any doubt, approach your firm's market data team who will be able to ask their Bloomberg contacts.

Edit:
As asked in the comments, it's useful to elaborate on the other possible parameters for the AuthorizationRequest.

"uuid" + "ipAddress"; this would be the default method of authenticating users for Server API.  On BPIPE this would require Bloomberg to explicitly enable it for you.   The UUID is the unique integer identifier assigned to each Bloomberg Anywhere user.  You can look this up in the terminal by running IAM

"emrsId" + "ipAddress"; "emrsId" is a deprecated alias for "authId".  This shouldn't be used anymore.

"authId" + "ipAddress"; "authId" is the String defined in EMRS (the BPIPE Entitlements Management and Reporting System) or SAPE (the Server API's equivalent of EMRS) that represents each user.  This would typically be that user's OS login details (e.g. DOMAIN/USERID) or Active Directory property (e.g. mail -> blah@blah.blah)

"authId" + "ipAddress" + "application"; "application" is the application name defined on EMRS/SAPE.  This will check to see whether the user defined in authId is enabled for the named application on EMRS.  Using one of these user+app style Identity objects in requests should record usage against both the user and application in the EMRS usage reports.

"token"; this is the preferred approach.  Using the session.generateToken functionality (which can be seen in the original question's code snippet) will result in an alphanumeric string.  You'd pass this as the only parameter into the Authorization request.   Note that the token generation system is virtualization-aware; if it detects it's running in Citrix or a remote desktop it will report the IP address of the display machine (or one hop towards where the user actually is).

Comment: When I pass "none" I get another issue and I think I should ask it somewhere else.
`Connecting to port 8194 on localhost
Not using authorization
blpapi.exception.UnsupportedOperationException: No subscription management endpoints for snapshot (0x00080013)`

Comment: Thanks @amkingTRP. Could you advise on the difference between setting `uuid`, `emrsId`, `authId` and `appName` and when you would use one vs the other? Also what do `emrsId` and `authId` refer to? The documenation in Bloomberg seems pretty sparse on this.

Comment: @Cagri This is probably due to Desktop API not supporting Snapshot functionality.  You should be pointing the hostname at your BPIPE.